# How to generate interface's name from string in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I need to find out my models and interfaces names based on string (it's coming from backend API). Now I have this code:

```js
const modelName = this.tableName; // for example: Product
const iName = modelName + 'Interface';
type interfaceName = iName;
const newInstance: BaseModelInterface<interfaceName> = Object.create(window[this.table_name].prototype);
```

The problem is coming from here:

```
export interface BaseModelInterface<T> {
  // ...
}
```

Because this using generic type I need to find out the name of the type. And this lines should be do this:

```js
const iName = modelName + 'Interface';
type interfaceName = iName;
```

But, the `type` isn't accept a variable's content as value.

How can I generate the interface's name from a variable's string value?

Comment: The problem is that `iName` is only available at runtime: there's no way TypeScript can check before hand what value it will resolve to. What about using a switch block that will simply assign the correct type? I suppose `iName` has a restricted set of values.

Comment: I think you have to keep in mind, that TypeScript will be compiled to JavaScript. JavaScript does not know about explicit types. Types and interfaces are just a convenience for TypeScript to avoid programming errors. They will not have any impact in runtime at all.

Comment: I know it will be plain JavaScript, still I have to define a type here. switch block isn't a good alternative, because I need to remain independent from backend API's changes. The backend team can put or delete table names from the list, and I don't want to depends on their work. I want a generic solution.

Comment: If the table names don't exist then you wouldn't hit the case that matches. It wouldn't break anything. In fact, your main worry should be creating corresponding types/models for the tables.

Comment: You may try to combine with Typescripts typeof to get runtime type

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with `newInstance` ? How do you plan to use it?

Comment: This code is awkward in TypeScript: `window[this.table_name].prototype`. Can you amend your question to explain it and show us the code behind? Then, we can see if a discriminated union can help with the expected type assertion `: BaseModelInterface<interfaceName>`.